# Xamarin Resource.Id doesn't recognize

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I've created new project (blank app) in Xamarin, but in the MainActivity.cs preset code are missing the button and SetContentView is commented. 
So i've added manually the code, but when i create the button using FindViewById he doesn't recognise Resource.Id and he mark .id as an error

**Resource.designer.cs**

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks", "1.0.0.0")]
public partial class Resource
{

    static Resource()
    {
        global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
    }

    public static void UpdateIdValues()
    {
    }

    public partial class Attribute
    {

        static Attribute()
        {
            global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
        }

        private Attribute()
        {
        }
    }

    public partial class Drawable
    {

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f020000
        public const int Icon = 2130837504;

        static Drawable()
        {
            global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
        }

        private Drawable()
        {
        }
    }

    public partial class Layout
    {

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030000
        public const int Main = 2130903040;

        static Layout()
        {
            global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
        }

        private Layout()
        {
        }
    }

    public partial class String
    {

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f040001
        public const int ApplicationName = 2130968577;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f040000
        public const int Hello = 2130968576;

        static String()
        {
            global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
        }

        private String()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivty.cs**

```
using System;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
    }
}
```

Error: "Resource" does not contain a definition for "id"

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the Resource class has been generated by Xamarin. You can find the file (`Resource.designer.cs`) under your Android project in the `Resources` folder. If it has not been generated, usually rebuilding the project will generate it again (unless there is a syntax error somewhere).

The Resource.Id class variables are generated for Views that are created in .axml files.

**Edit based after the answers in the comments to be complete:**

The `Resources` class should contain an inner `Id` class, which it apparently doesn't. This can happen if there is a syntax error in you .axml files, because in that case the `Resources.designer.cs`file won't be regenerated. Or you haven't set an id at all, you would add the id like this: `<Button android:id="@+id/myButton" />`

Comment: Resource class has been generated by Xamarin

Comment: Please add the contents of the `MainActivity.cs`, `Resources.designer.cs` and the exact error you get to your question.

Comment: Ok, i've added the contents

Comment: You pasted the `Resources.designer.cs` content twice, `MainActivity.cs` is missing. The `Resources` class should contain an inner `Id` class, which it doesn't. How did you set the id of the button in the Main.axml file? Make sure you set the `id` like this: `<Button android:id="@+id/myButton" />`

Comment: Added MainActivity.cs. I can't add the button because error

Comment: How did you add the button to the Main.axml (like I asked in my previous comment)? If you missed the `android:id` part, no `Id` class will be generated. Also keep in mind that if your Main.axml contains invalid syntax, the `Resources.designer.cs` file will not be regenerated either.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you tried already, but try to rebuild the project: Build->Rebuild All. I told you this because I have had similar problems and I solved rebuilding the project. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've solved the problem! Was missing `<Button android:id="@+id/myButton" />` in Main.xml and there was a syntax error in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Clean -> Rebuild All. If still cant find the Resource Id, restart Visual Studio. Im using 2019.

Answer (score 0):

the error might be because you change the namespace but doesn't update the entire project namespace so :
-make sure namespace in all the project files are same
-check namespace  in the "Resource.designer.cs" file in the solution explorer

- and the important part open the "Project Properties" from the VS Project Menu and make sure that the "default namespace" and "assemply Name" in the "Application" are the same as your entire project name space.